# Post blog messages on Facebook wall using PHP

Tags: php, facebook

I would like to be able to automatically post on Facebook Wall from my Blog website posts. For example, once a user posted on my blog website using a form, the message will automatically be posted on Facebook Wall(Similar to Twitter). How can we do this using PHP?

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How to add your blog to facebook is [explained on facebook](https://www.facebook.com/notes/blogging-with-beth/how-to-publish-your-blog-posts-to-facebook-automatically/245596473016).

How to add comments to facebook is [explained here](http://raventools.com/blog/facebook-comments/).

And Google has a lot of other resources if you search for that topic.